# Rspec: Capybara helper not finding link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

Building a basic blog app to push me to learn TDD so I'm fairly new. I'm having issues getting Capybara to recognize a link. Seems as if all the elements are in place so I'm confused at what I am missing..

Here is the failure:

```
  1) PostsController#GET create with valid attributes creates a post by the current_user
     Failure/Error: sign_in(build_stubbed(:user))
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find link "Sign Up"
     # ./spec/support/authentication_helpers.rb:7:in `sign_in'
     # ./spec/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb:44:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**spec/support/authentication_helper.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

module AuthenticationHelpers

    def sign_in(x)
        visit root_path
        click_link "Sign Up"
        fill_in "First Name", with: x.first_name
        fill_in "Last Name", with: x.last_name
        fill_in "Email", with: x.email
        fill_in "Password", with: x.password
        fill_in "Password Confirmation", with: x.password
        click_button "Sign Up"
    end
end
```

**spec/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb**

```
describe '#GET create' do
    context 'with valid attributes' do
      before :each do
        post :create, post: attributes_for(:post)
      end

          it { expect(Post.count).to eq(1) }
          it { expect(flash[:success]).to eq('Your post has been saved!') }
          it { expect(assigns(:post)).to be_a(Post) }
          it { expect(assigns(:post)).to be_persisted }
          it { expect(response).to redirect_to Post.first }

          it "creates a post by the current_user" do
            sign_in(build_stubbed(:user))
            @post = Post.last
            expect(@post.user).to eq(user)
          end
    end
```

**_header.html.erb**

```
        <div class="cbp-af-header">
            <div class="cbp-af-inner">
                <nav>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                    <a href="#"><%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_path %></a>
                    <a href="#"><%= link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path %></a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**rake routes**

```
           Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                 Controller#Action
            users GET    /users(.:format)                            users#index
                  POST   /users(.:format)                            users#create
         new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                        users#new
        edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                   users#edit
             user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                        users#show
                  PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                        users#update
                  PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                        users#update
                  DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                        users#destroy
    user_sessions POST   /user_sessions(.:format)                    user_sessions#create
 new_user_session GET    /user_sessions/new(.:format)                user_sessions#new
             root GET    /                                           posts#index
    post_comments GET    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                  POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
 new_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
edit_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
     post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                  PATCH  /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                  PUT    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                  DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
            posts GET    /posts(.:format)                            posts#index
                  POST   /posts(.:format)                            posts#create
         new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                        posts#new
        edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                   posts#edit
             post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#show
                  PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                  PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                  DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#destroy
            admin GET    /admin(.:format)                            admin/dashboard#index
```

In case this info is relevant; authentication was built from scratch and I haven't implemented authorization yet.

Answer (score 0):

'Sign Up' is a link, not a button, so you need to use `click_link` (or `click`, which works with both kinds).

Comment: I'm a bit confused. The failure is on line 7 (directly after `visit root_path`) which is where it initially clicks the link "Sign Up" to go to the sign up page where it then fills out the form, finishing off with `click_button` "Sign Up". When I simply use `click`, I get the error `Undefined method 'click'`.